# Accessing/Setting dev express dropdown with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, devexpress

I have two dev express dropdown controls, one containing "Product Type" and one Containing "Delivery Method".  There is one element of each that are directly related to each other in that if one is selected, the other should be selected as well.

The controls are currently declared as such:

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox runat="server" ID="cbDeliveryMethod" ValueField="Id" 
    TextField="Name" ClientIDMode="Static" ClientInstanceName="cbDeliveryMethod">
        <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="cbDeliveryMethodSelection" />
</dx:ASPxComboBox>

<dx:ASPxComboBox runat="server" ID="cbProductType" ValueField="Id"
     ValueType="System.String" TextField="Name" ClientIDMode="Static"
     ClientInstanceName="cbProductType">
            <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="cbProductTypeSelection" />
</dx:ASPxComboBox>
```

The controls render as:

```
<input class="..." id="cbProductType_I" name="ct100$MainContent$uc...$...cbProductType">
    ....
<input class="..." id="cbDeliveryMethod_I" name="ct100$MainContent$uc...$...$cbDeliveryMethod" >
```

and my javascript is currently defined as:

```
function cbProductTypeSelection(s, e) {
    console.log("product type");
    var alertMe = $('#cbDeliveryMethod_I').val();
    console.log(alertMe);  // :(
    // $('#cbDeliveryMethod').val('required delivery method here');
    debugger;
}

function cbDeliveryMethodSelection(s, e) {
    console.log("delviery method");
    var alertMe = $('#cbProductType').val();
    console.log(alertMe);  // :(
    // $('#cbProductType').val('required product type here');
    debugger;
}
```

I'm trying to do this all in javascript to avoid the page post-back. The loggers currently come back with empty strings, so I'm led to believe that I'm not properly retrieving the controls.  I've been trying to use this resource as a reference: [Dev Express & JQuery](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18561)

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Comment: I don't know.  I guess this place is just my first instinct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the client-side **GetValue/SetValue** or **GetText/SetText** methods:
...

```
function cbProductTypeSelection(s, e) {
    var ownValue = s.GetValue();
    var ownText = s.GetText();

    //ClientInstanceName="cbDeliveryMethod"

    var cbDeliveryMethodValue = cbDeliveryMethod.GetValue();
    var cbDeliveryMethodText = cbDeliveryMethod.GetText();
}

function cbDeliveryMethodSelection(s, e) {
    var ownValue = s.GetValue();
    var ownText = s.GetText();

    //ClientInstanceName="cbProductType"

    var cbProductTypeValue = cbProductType.GetValue();
    var cbProductTypeText = cbProductType.GetText();
}
```

Comment: But I want to edit the value of another drop down. s refers to the drop down that was selected, correct?  So if ProductType is selected, then I automatically set the Delivery Method drop down to the corresponding value.

Comment: I have updated my Answer. Use the ClientInstanceName in the JavaScript code to access the corresponding ASPxComboBox client-side members/API.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware that simply setting the client instance name let me access it directly with javascript.